# Expressing $16b^3a^2(6ab^4)(ab)^3$ in the form $2^m3^na^rb^s$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, exponentiation

In Chapter 1.3, Basic Mathematics, Serge Lang, there is the question:

> Express the following expression in the form $2^m3^na^rb^s$, where $m, n, r, s$ are positive integers:$$16b^3a^2(6ab^4)(ab)^3$$

The answer I got was $16 \cdot 6 \cdot a^6 \cdot b^{10}$.

Is there something I did wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track, just not quite finished:

$16*6=2^4 * 2 * 3=2^5 * 3^1$

Comment: Now I get it. I struggled with that one for a while there.. will +1 when I have enough rep.

Answer (score 5):

What you've done *so far* is correct... but we need to do a little more...

$$16 \times  6 = 2^4\times 2 \times 3 = 2^5 \times 3$$

So we have that $$16 \cdot 6 \cdot a^6 \cdot b^{10} = 2^5\cdot 3^1\cdot a^6\cdot b^{10}$$

Comment: Deserves a thumbs up! +1

Comment: Great answer, except the working shows $2^5$ but concluded $2^4$. +1. Also, thanks for the $\cdot$ edit. Couldn't figure out where to find the symbol.

Comment: It's just `\cdot` for formatting "$\cdot$"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $16\cdot 6$ is not yet in the form $2^m\cdot 3^n$. Otherwise it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

$6$ isn't a power of $3$.  You'll want to change $16\cdot 6$ to $32\cdot 3$.

Answer (score 2):

Great question, believe it or not, these same questions from that same book stumped me at one point.

This might help you out.

[Express each of the following expressions in the form $2^m3^na^rb^s$, where $m$, $n$,$ r$ and $ s$ are positive integers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171596/express-each-of-the-following-expressions-in-the-form-2m3narbs-where-m)

The goal here is to reduce everything to it's smallest factors. In these questions they all reduce to smallest factors in the form $2^m3^na^rb^s$.

Comment: When I couldn't figure out what the exercise was asking, your [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171596/) was indispensable. That helped me solve `(a)` but `(b)` had me stumped. I couldn't figure out how to reduce $16 \cdot 6$ to $2^m \cdot 3^n$. +1 on your original question.